# How to open Maya without UI?

Tags: python, maya

I'm currently making an Arnold batch-renderer in Python.
I would like to open a maya scene without the UI and what I have is: `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\bin\mayapy.exe`

I don't know what to do, because this is too abstract for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a good tutorial/blog which helped me with mayapy :

- http://www.toadstorm.com/blog/?p=136
- http://www.chadvernon.com/blog/resources/python-scripting-for-maya-artists/python-in-maya/

but basicly, you just have to run a shell and then type :

```
mayapy /somepath/myscript.py
```

the script initializing maya standalone :

```
import maya.standalone as standalone
standalone.initialize(name='python')
```

and then any python command you want to run : opening a file, set up some settings, launch a render...etc